# Как сделать произвольную фигуру в CSS

Tags: html, css

нужна срочная помощь с одним объектом в верстке.
Как сделать такую фигуру[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выпить краску, плюнуть на лист бумаги, растереть, софотографировать, поместить фотку в html

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а ведь в теории должно сработать!

Answer (score 4):

Если "поиграться" с этими значениями, можно подогнать что-то похожее.

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.decoration-box {
  pointer-events: none;
  border-top: 70px solid purple;
  border-right: 70px solid purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  filter: blur(65px);
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="decoration-box"></div>
</body>
```

Но всё же, я бы вам рекомендовал скачать эту картинку как png и установить как фон

---

**UPD**
Либо ещё такой вариант:

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.decoration-box {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(20deg) scale(2);
  filter: blur(30px);
  margin: 100px;
}

.decoration-box__line {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 45px;
  width: 120px;
}

.decoration-box__line:first-child {
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.decoration-box__line:last-child {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="decoration-box">
    <div class="decoration-box__line"></div>
    <div class="decoration-box__line"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Но вариант с png лучше